# How to share raw disks between instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, disk

I want to setup cluster and want 3 raw disks of 1 GB each which must be shared between 2 instances on GCP. How can I do that? Is there any documentation or a method where I can create raw disks of 1 GB each and share it on 2 instances?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation [Share a zonal persistent disk between multiple instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#use_multi_instances):

> **You can attach a non-boot persistent disk to more than one virtual machine 
>   instance in read-only mode, which allows you to share static
>   data between multiple instances**. Sharing static data between
>   multiple instances from one persistent disk is cheaper than
>   replicating your data to unique disks for individual instances.
>
> **If you attach a persistent disk to multiple instances, all of those instances must attach the persistent disk in read-only mode**. It is
>   not possible to attach the persistent disk to multiple instances in
>   read-write mode.

To attach disk to each of your VMs use [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk):

```
$ gcloud compute instances attach-disk NAME_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE --disk NAME_OF_SHARED_DISK --mode ro
```

and then connect to the instances and mount the disk.

[`--multi-write`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/disks/create#--multi-writer) flag for persistent disks available only in alfa version (*do not use it in production environment*):

> Create the disk in shared mode so that it can be attached with
>   read-write access to multiple VMs. Available only for zonal disks.
>   Cannot be used with regional disks. Shared disk is exposed only as an
>   NVMe device. Shared PD does not yet support resize and snapshot
>   operations.

In addition, have a look at some possible alternatives:

1. managed solutions:

   - [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets)
   - [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore)
   - [Elastifile](https://www.elastifile.com/) ([acquired by Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/inside-google-cloud/expanding-our-enterprise-file-storage-offerings-to-simplify-the-management-and-scaling-of-data))
   - [NetApp Cloud Volumes](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#netapp)
   - [Panzura](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#panzura)
2. run on your own:

   - distributed filesystem like [Ceph](https://ceph.io/), [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/)
   - [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [Samba](https://www.samba.org/)
   - single VM as a data storage node with [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs)